# postgresql - Error: Connection terminated

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to add data to my empty table. In the following codes, I was able to log the client. That means connection to the database was successful. However, when it went to the first client.query, it gave me the error: Connection terminated. The database was left untouched. I log the result and result was undefined.

Is the termination caused by undefined result or by other reasons? I am new to database. I tried to google the answer but couldn't find any clues. Can anyone help?

```
function greetUserText(userId) {
  //first read user firstname
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/' + userId,
    qs: {
      access_token: config.FB_PAGE_TOKEN
    }

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var user = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log("getUserData:" + user);

      if (user.first_name) {

        var pool = new pg.Pool(config.PG_CONFIG);
        pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
            }
                    console.log('cccccccccccccc', client);
            var rows = [];

            client.query(`SELECT id FROM users WHERE fb_id='${userId}' LIMIT 1`,
                function(err, result) {
                    console.log('query result ' + result);
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Query error: ' + err);
                    } else {
                    console.log('rows: ' + result.rows.length);
                        if (result.rows.length === 0) {
                          let sql = 'INSERT INTO users (fb_id, first_name, last_name, profile_pic, ' +
                              'locale, timezone, gender) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)';
                          console.log('sql: ' + sql);
                          client.query(sql,
                            [
                                userId,
                                user.first_name,
                                user.last_name,
                                user.profile_pic,
                                user.locale,
                                user.timezone,
                                user.gender
                             ]
                                     );
                         }
                    }
               });

          done();
        });
        pool.end();

        // console.log("FB user: %s %s, %s",
        //  user.first_name, user.last_name, user.gender);

        sendTextMessage(userId, "Welcome " + user.first_name + '! ' + "I can answer FAQs for you" + " and I can perform job interviews.");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You are calling `done()` in the wrong place. It is supposed to be called after the last query finished execution.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks. You mean putting it right after the inner client.query? I tired that I can now get the result and log the sql. However, I got the following error:

Comment: query result [object Object]
rows: 0
sql: INSERT INTO users (fb_id, first_name, last_name, profile_pic, locale, timezone, gender) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
(node:3299) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Connection terminated by user

Comment: @vitaly-t where shall I put the done(); ? Thanks.

Comment: Connections are a nightmare.That's why there is [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), so you don't have to deal with them at all.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment/remove the `done();`